# Unable to persist the shell environment with rvm set, for executing further commands through a ruby script

Tags: ruby, rvm

I need to programmatically set the ruby version -> execute bundler -> and other commands from within a Ruby script [**Note:** do not wish to do this using a shell script, it has to be through ruby itself].

Since executing ruby scripts / irb use '**sh**' by default, and RVM works with '**bash/zsh**', I managed to set the ruby version using rvm & bash with the following command:
`%x[bash -lc "rvm use #{ruby_ver}" 2>&1]`.

**Problem:** After this, if I run any system command (like bundle install), it doesn't execute in the same bash shell where I set the ruby version, but as a new shell (again considering **'sh'**), and hence the execution environment differs from what's needed.

Even on running further commands with `%x[bash -lc #{command}]`, it is treated as a different shell.

Is there any way to:
Change the shell to bash for the entire ruby script execution period OR Persist the shell where RVM was fired OR Any better way to handle this scenario

Appreciate any help at all.

Comment: A better way to handle this scenario is to use a shell script, not a ruby script. Why are you trying to do this using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use something like session([gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/session), [sources](https://github.com/ahoward/session)), there are other gems that do the same but this one is one of the best.

Install the gem:

```
gem install session
```

Use it:

```
require 'session'
bash = Session::Bash.new

bash.execute( 'long_running_command.exe' ) do |out, err|
  logger << out if out
  elogger << err if err
end
```

I have an gem that uses session for wrapping rvm - rvm-with([gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rvm-with), [sources](https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-with)).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks mpapis..!

Answer (score 0):

Each Ruby shellout happens in its own, discrete shell. You could maybe do something like use popen to spawn a bash shell, then pipe your commands to it, but all you're doing then is running a bash script.

Your better bet would be to create a full bash script, then to execute it with `rvm do` to run it in the context of your chosen RVM environment. You can invoke this from ruby, by executing something like `rvm do 2.0.0 bundle install && rake` or whatever, but at the end of the day, you're talking about running shell commands, so you should be doing it with shell syntax.